# xml generation from php if file doesnt exist

Tags: php, xml

This code works if file is previously expisting but if file doesn't exist this code doesnt work.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->version = '1.0';
        $doc->encoding = 'ISO-8859-1';
        $response = $doc->createElement('response');
        $doc->appendChild($response);
        $response_type= $doc->createElement('response_type','Yes');
        $response_id = $doc->createElement('response_id',$max_id_site);
        $response->appendChild($response_type);
        $response->appendChild($response_id);
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        echo $doc->saveXML();
        $doc->save('$filename_xml');
```

updated code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->version = '1.0';
        $doc->encoding = 'ISO-8859-1';
        $response = $doc->createElement('response');
        $doc->appendChild($response);
        $response_type= $doc->createElement('response_type','Yes');
        $response_id = $doc->createElement('response_id',$max_id_site);
        $response->appendChild($response_type);
        $response->appendChild($response_id);
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        echo $doc->saveXML();
        if (! is_file($filename_xml)) {
            touch($filename_xml) or trigger_error("Can't Create File");
            $doc->save($filename_xml);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace

```
$doc->save('$filename_xml');
```

with

```
if (! is_file($filename_xml)) {
    touch($filename_xml) or trigger_error("Can't Create File");
    $doc->save($filename_xml);
}
```

Comment: $doc->save($filename_xml); this i alredy tried it doesnt works and is_file($filename_xml) wont be helpful i think.

Comment: Its not what you have ... there is a difference .. you are using quotes `'` and you are not checking of the file exists

Comment: iif( file_exists( $filename_xml ) == false ) {
  $doc->save( $filename_xml );
} i used this code then also it doesnt works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_exists()` to check if file is already there.

Replace last line:

```
$doc->save('$filename_xml');
```

with

```
if( file_exists( $filename_xml ) == false ) {
  $doc->save( $filename_xml );
}
```

In general you should not even generate the xml if file is there.

BTW: Putting `$filename_xml`) in "`" is wrong.

Comment: it doesnt works........now i dynamically access file and it give an error:404 file not found.........means no xml is being created